# Pagination with spatie always shows paginateroute::paginateroute in url

Tags: laravel, pagination

Why is my url like this
`example.test/blog/paginateroute::paginateroute.page/2` using [spatie/laravel-paginateroute](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-paginateroute)

my route :

```
Route::paginate('blog', [ 'as' => 'blog', 'uses' => 'BlogController@index' ] );
```

on views

```
@if(PaginateRoute::hasPreviousPage())
    <a href="{{ PaginateRoute::previousPageUrl() }}"> « </a>
@endif

@if(PaginateRoute::hasNextPage($posts))
    <a href="{{ PaginateRoute::nextPageUrl($posts) }}"> » </a>
@endif
```

what is solution for remove paginateroute::paginateroute. from url ?

Comment: Spatie is a web design company and has over 200 projects on github. You need to be more specific on which one you're actually using.

Comment: @apokryfos It's laravel-paginateroute...